# Confluent-Kafka-Python: Get lag per topic partition

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-python

With [confluent-kafka-python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) was wondering if via the `Admin API` or any of the other api's, I can fetch lag per `topic partition`?
Found this [link to be helpful](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/list_offsets.py) but wanted to check if there is a direct api available instead?

Comment: Check how https://github.com/sivann/kafkatop does this using the same library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the AdminClient.

You can get the high watermark of a topic's partitions and you can get the consumer's current/committed positions directly from the Consumer instance, as the linked example shows... Subtract these, and you have the lag.

Alternatively, you can install tool like Burrow and use its REST API from Python